# How can I hide the Window which sends a command using commanding in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding

I am using WPF and I try to follow MVVM.
So I have a VM which has my Model as a property. The Model has a property which is a list of model1, which implements a command.
The reason why I don't want to move the command to the ViewModel, so I would have access to the view is that I don't know how many elements my list will have and I want to be sure that my command access its model1.
This commands also does some processing and I want the window, which holds the button binded to the command, to hide, during this processing.
How can I achieve this? Where should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this, it is best if your ViewModel has the command, and it takes a parameter. That way, you will be passed the item that the user is trying to modify. So if you have a `ItemsControl`:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Name, StringFormat=Push {0}}"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.ItemPushedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In your ViewModel, you would define your command like so (I'm using the DelegateCommand from [prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/), you can use whatever command you are comfortable with):

```cs
private readonly DelegateCommand<Model> itemPushedCommand;

public ICommand ItemPushedCommand { get { return itemPushedCommand; } }

public MyViewModel()
{
    itemPushedCommand = new DelegateCommand<Model>(OnItemPushed);
}

private void OnItemPushed(Model item)
{
    // your item has been pushed!
}
```

Comment: and inside OnItemPushed I can call item's routine. Thank you for your answer, it is what I was looking for.